# Can Ratchet be used for multiple sconnections?

Tags: php, chat, ratchet

I wanted to develop a chat application for my website so on learning I found that websocket is the best solution for real time communication and hence I decided to use [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/).

I am able to set it up and create a basic chat application.Here is the Chat class.

```
class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface
{
    protected $clients;    

    public function __construct() 
    {    
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) 
    {
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) 
    {            
        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if($client !== $from)
                $client->send($msg);
        }
    }
    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
    } 
    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e)
    {
        echo "The following error occured :".$e->getMessage();
        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

But I have following questions before I proceed (or can proceed) further:

1. Can I use Ratchet for private communication between two users?
2. How does Ratchet scale? I mean if I have a website with 1 million users and I am allowing anyone to chat with anyone, than is it possible? Or I am restricted to create limited public chat rooms (like SO) where anyone can 
   join?

Comment: Could you please update us with what you found?